# How to connect FX controller with main app

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I have a main app class and a fxmlController class but I am entangled in connecting/organizing(confused how these are called and how I should organize them to make the GUI connected business logic) business logic and GUI. Can someone please tell the order in which following function are called or can anyone help how I should call them?

### Main class:

```
public void Main()        //constructor
public static void main() // our main
public void start()       //I don't know what it is, what purpose it has
                          // and where should be called
                          //Note: In main function there is a call as following
```

### fxmlController class:

```
public void initialize()  //I don't know what it is and what purpose it has
public fxmlController()   // which function should be called here....
```

NOTE: I know about `FXMLLoader();` please someone explain

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think of an FXML file and its corresponding controller as a pair that manage the user interface. In larger applications you might have several such FXML-controller pairs that make up different parts of the user interface. Within each pair, the FXML file defines the layout of the UI, and the controller defines the logic (i.e. it typically processes user input, etc).

While you said you "know about `FXMLLoader`", if you understand that fully you would actually understand some of the other things you asked about, so:

The user interface defined by an FXML file and its controller is loaded into memory by an `FXMLLoader`. In the simplest setup, the controller is defined by a `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file. When the `load()` method is called on the `FXMLLoader`, it:

1. Loads the FXML file
2. Creates an instance of the controller class specified by the `fx:controller` attribute, by calling its no-argument constructor
3. Sets the value of any `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller to the elements defined with matching `fx:id` attributes
4. Registers any event handlers mapping to methods in the controller
5. Calls the `initialize()` method on the controller, if there is one.

Notice the order of those events: the constructor is called *before* the `@FXML`-annotated fields are injected, but the `initialize()` method is called after. This means you can access (and configure) and `@FXML`-annotated fields in the `initialize()` method, but not in the constructor. It is quite common (at least in simple applications) not to define any constructor in the controller classes and just to use the default.

You can have as many FXML/controller pairs in your application as you need/want. Each FXML file should have its own controller class. You can load an FXML file as many times as you need if you want multiple instances of the UI it defines: each time the `FXMLLoader` will create a new controller instance for you that is associated with the UI element you loaded.

The `Application` subclass (you called it `Main`) represents the entire application. You should have only one such class per application and only one instance of it, which is created for you by the FX toolkit.

When you start a FX application (which I'll describe below), the FX toolkit is started. Then an instance of your `Application` subclass is created, and its `init()` method is called (if you don't define one, the default implementation does nothing). The FX Application Thread is then started and the `Application` subclass instance's `start()` method is called on that thread.

Your `start()` method should do pretty minimal work. Typically it will load your "main" fxml file, place the resulting UI in a scene, put the scene in the stage, and show the stage. All the logic will be handled by the controller for the FXML file, not by the `Application` subclass.

In more advanced applications, you might start some background services and/or create some data models in your `init()` method, and connect them with the controller in the `start()` method, but the ideas above are the basics.

The actual startup process can happen in a couple of ways. If you are using the standard Oracle JRE, then launching an `Application` subclass with

```
java Main
```

(where `Main extends Application`) will cause the process above to happen; in other words the FX toolkit is started, an instance of `Main` is created, its `init()` method is called, and it's `start()` method is called on the FX Application Thread.

Other environments (particularly IDEs) are not aware of the JavaFX startup process, and expect the class you are executing to have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method, like any standard Java application class. To support these environments, it is common for your `Application` subclass to define a `main(...)` method which simply calls `launch(...)` (a static method inherited from `Application`). The `launch` method forces the FX toolkit to start, etc. It can only be called once during any application lifetime.

So now you have something like:

```
package com.example ;

// imports...

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // just load fxml file and display it in the stage:

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("mainUI.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // main method to support non-JavaFX-aware environments:

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // starts the FX toolkit, instantiates this class, 
        // and calls start(...) on the FX Application thread:
        launch(args); 
    }
}
```

Then you would have mainUI.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import java.util.ArrayList?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.MyController">
    <Label  fx:id="label1"/>
    <Label  fx:id="label2"/>
</VBox>
```

and the controller

```
package com.example ;

// imports...

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private Label label1 ;
    @FXML
    private Label label2 ;

    // called by the FXML loader after the labels declared above are injected:
    public void initialize() {

        // do initialization and configuration work...

        // trivial example, could also be done directly in the fxml:
        label1.setText("Foo");
        label2.setText("Bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer explaining the JavaFX machinery, thank you!

Comment: @James_D , perfect explanation. I am trying to make kind of a game where simple geometric figures are drawn on the Canvas and moving according to some algorithm. Could you please tell me if I should write that piece of code (drawing on canvas and moving logic) in the init() of Main or in the Controller class? Thanks you!

Comment: Drawing on canvas in the View class, according to parameters received from controller class which handles user events. The move logic affects the state of the data so it should be in the Model class methods.

Comment: @Trunk Did you intend to post this comment on a different post? It appears to have nothing at all to do with this question or answer: there is no canvas here, and the OP is not asking about MVC (or similar patterns) or separation between model and view, but about JavaFX lifecycle methods.

Comment: It didn't pertain to the OP question which you handled but I commented anyways. Sorry if it's not kosher to do this.

Comment: @Trunk No, that's fine, but I don't really see what it has to do with the answer either. The sample code here doesn't maintain any data, so there isn't a model, per se. Again, the question (and consequently the answer) are about the lifecycle (or at least the start process) of a JavaFX application as it relates to loading FXML and creating the associated "controller" (really a presenter imo). Discussion of a model (of which there is plenty [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864)) would simply confuse the issue.

Comment: I was answering the comment-question made by Fabi immediately above my first comment. Fabi's question was not germane to the OP's question but showed a similar confusion about the way we are supposed to apply JavaFX graphics. I was sympathetic to this - indeed I'd arrived at this thread when Googling whether a class extending Application could be launched from outside by its Controller class or if this was not the 'right' way. Launching a JavaFX application by running the main method within Application class seemed to require keeping the original View open after a new View is opened.

Comment: @Trunk Use `@` to reply to a specific user/comment (e.g. `@Fabi` in this case). It will make the context of your comment clearer, and will also notify the relevant user of the comment. In terms of the content of your last comment, it sounds like you are still confusing the `Application` subclass (which represents the lifecycle of the entire application) with a particular view (which in any real application should be separated from the `Application` class). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698 and perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739199

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149758/discussion-between-trunk-and-james-d).

Answer (score 2):

The controller is binded in you fxml file or where you call the main view for the first time.

So you can use the `fx:controller` attribute in the xml or the `FXMLLoader#setController()` method from your launcher.