# Strange behavior using a variable in a JavaFX application

Tags: variables, javafx, lwjgl, fxml

I am writing a very basic 3D modelling program. I've used LWJGL to render my objects and JavaFX to provide an user interface in a separate window, new thread.

As I saw JavaFX likes to take control over the application, but in my case this was not an option. I tried to pass my already created scene graph to the JavaFX controller class, but I didn't find a way doing this properly.

It's seems to be **impossible to pass anything from outside into the main JavaFX class.** The start method loads the layout from an FXML file with reflection magic, but this method is called in the constructor, therefore variables are not initialized. Defining a new constructor with parameters throws an exception (class cannot be initialized).

After struggling many hours, I gave up, I've decided to create a new scene graph in the JavaFX controller and created a getter method to it.

```
public class Toolbox extends Application implements Runnable {

    private ToolboxLogic logic = new ToolboxLogic(); //controller, the scene graph is instantiated

    ...

    public SceneGraph getSceneGraph() {
        return logic.sceneGraph; // returns the scene graph
    }
}
```

Not a beautiful solution, but it shall work, I said. But it doesn't.
I tried to load a file in two locations:

- with code written in the LWJGL renderer
- with buttons, calling a method in the controller

If I load a file from the renderer, my objects **show up on the screen, but I cannot navigate with the buttons**, only the root node appears in the scene graph.

If I load a file from the user interface, **I can navigate on the tree, but it doesn't show up in the renderer**.

It seems like here

```
return logic.sceneGraph;
```

Java would have done a deep copy instead of returning a pointer, and each part of my program is working with its own version of the scene graph.

What is a problem, and how can I make it work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing about lwgjl, so I don't know what constraints it puts on your application structure. The intention in JavaFX, however, is that the `start(...)` method should be the entry point (startup) for your application: i.e. it is the equivalent of (or replacement for) `main(...)` in a "traditional" Java application. So basically there is nothing to pass to the application subclass: anything you need is created from that point on. See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739199 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698 help.

Comment: I've seen that JavaFX tries to be the entry point in the application, but my design could not be rewritten to use entirely JavaFX's approach. I got around this problem by using a static variable, it is good for my project, but is a really ugly solution. Although, I could not understand why it behaves this way, why I could not get a variable when it was non-static. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Impossible to answer that without you showing how you are exposing the instance of `Toolbox` that is created when you call `launch()` (assuming you call `launch()` somewhere). If you can't use the standard approach, you can use the technique in my answer to the first link in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working by setting the scene graph static. Strange! Now, I'm really curious, why it behaves like this.