# too many different javafx stages

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 sides of the MVC. on the model side, is where i have my main class for the entire battleship program. It instantiates the view/controller side of things, which consists of 3 different windows(classes that extend Application): a PreBoard, which gets both players names, and then one player board each (P1Board, P2Board). In all 3 of these separate classes, they extend Application, and all have a start(Stage primaryStage) method.

Since ive been reading about javaFX threading for the last 48 hours i am still barely understanding where the javaFX application thread starts. Does the javaFX Application thread start the very first time that Application.launch() is called, even if you have 3 seperate classes that extend Application and have their own start methods?

My original intentions were to have a window where players can enter their names, then a separate window with their own board, and i have failed MISERABLY because im getting more and more exceptions the longer the whole program runs.

So the question is, where the hell does the javaFX Application thread start?

Main class, on the model side

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package battleship.model;
import battleship.viewcon.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author foolishklown
 */
public class MainApp {
    Player player1;
    Player player2;
    BattleshipGame theGame;
    PreBoard theGamePreBoard;
    ViewCon viewConnector;



    public void go() {
        theGamePreBoard = new PreBoard();
        theGamePreBoard.setMainAppConnection(this);
        viewConnector = theGamePreBoard.getVcon();

    }



    public void startBsGame(String[] names) {                
        theGame = new BattleshipGame(names[0], names[1]);        
        viewConnector.setGame(theGame);

    }

    public BattleshipGame getGame() {
        return theGame;
    }

    public void setConnection(ViewCon vc) {
        this.viewConnector = vc;
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainApp app = new MainApp();
        app.go();           

    }       

}
```

PreBoard code, which instantiates 2 other classes that extend Application and have their own start methods......

```
package battleship.viewcon;
import battleship.model.*;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

/**
 * PreBoard class, used for getting user input for players names
 * @author Chris Wilson
 * @author Bob McHenry
 * @author Mario Rodriguez De la Raza en la casa!
 * @author Jessy Bernoudi
 */
public class PreBoard extends Application {
    private boolean turn; // field to determine which players name to put into which board
    private String player;       
    private Button hideBtn;
    private Button showBtn;
    private TextField userText;
    private ViewCon controller;    
    private P1Board p1B;
    private P2Board p2B;
    private BattleshipGame game;
    private String[] playerNames;
    private MainApp mainApp;



    /**
     * Application class override method, where javaFX stage starts
     * @param primaryStage 
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {   
        playerNames = new String[2];               
        turn = false;       
        p1B = new P1Board();
        p2B = new P2Board();
        controller = new ViewCon();
        controller.setPreB(this); 
        controller.setp1(p1B);
        controller.setp2(p2B);               
        controller.setMain();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Battleship setup"); //Main stage (window container)      
        //Gridpane for using rows/columns for child node placement
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(100, 25, 25, 25));

        // label in window
        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Setup");
        sceneTitle.setId("setup-text");
        grid.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

        // label and textfield
        Label userName = new Label("Enter Player1 UserName:");
        userName.setId("user-name");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);        
        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        userTextField.setId("text-field");
        grid.add(userTextField, 0, 2);

        // button for setup, with actionListener to save player name or default if its left blank
        Button setupBtn = new Button("Setup Board");        
        HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
        hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        hbBtn.getChildren().add(setupBtn);
        grid.add(hbBtn, 0, 3);

        setupBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // determine which player name to use to pass into which player board
                if(turn == false) {            
                    String temp1 = userTextField.getText();
                        if(temp1.equals("")) {
                            player = "Player1";
                        } else {
                            player = temp1;
                        }
                        playerNames[0] = player;
                        controller.setPlayer1(player);                       
                        turn = true;                        
                        p1B.start(new Stage());
                        grid.getChildren().remove(userTextField);
                        userText = new TextField();
                        userText.setId("text-field");
                        grid.add(userText, 0, 2);
                        userName.setText("Enter Player2 username:");                        
                } else {                    
                    String temp2 = userText.getText();
                        if(temp2.equals("")) {
                            player = "Player2";
                        } else {
                            player = temp2;
                        }
                        playerNames[1] = player;                        
                        controller.startGame(playerNames);
                        controller.setPlayer2(player);                                               
                        p2B.start(new Stage());                                               
                        p1B.primeShow();

                }                        
            }
        });        

        hideBtn = new Button();        
        hideBtn.setId("hideBtn");
        hideBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primaryStage.hide();
            }
        });

        showBtn = new Button();
        showBtn.setId("showBtn");
        showBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { 
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primaryStage.show();
            }
        });

        controller.setPreShowBtn(showBtn);
        controller.setPreHideBtn(hideBtn);
        // Add the entire scene into the main window(stage) after setting the scene dimensions
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 580, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        // Attach css stylesheet
        scene.getStylesheets().add(PreBoard.class.getResource("styles/PreBoardStyle.css").toExternalForm());
        // Show this window(stage) upon instantiation
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param v
     */
    public void setLink(ViewCon v) {        
        this.controller = v;        
    }   

    /**
     *
     * @param b
     */
    public void setBattleshipGame(BattleshipGame b) {
        this.game = b;        
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param main
     */
    public void setMainAppConnection(MainApp main) {        
        this.mainApp = main;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public MainApp getMainConnection() {        
        return mainApp;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public ViewCon getVcon() {
        return controller;
    }

    public void exitPre() {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }



}
```

Comment: "Does the javaFX Application thread start the very first time that Application.launch() is called": the FX Application Thread is started the ***one and only time*** you call `Application.launch()` (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-)).

Comment: I think you are also confused about the `Application` class. You should have only one `Application` subclass in your application, and only one instance of it (which is created for you when you call `launch()`, or launch the application directly from the command line). `Application` does not represent a window: `Stage` represents a window. So if you need multiple windows, create multiple `Stage` instances, but you should not have additional `Application` classes. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are