# Instantiating a web view media player within a JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I am writing a piece of educational software, and want the user to be able to select a video to watch from a list that lies within my JavaFX GUI.
I have created a `mediaPlayer` class that contains a main method that runs the code and displays the video correctly, 
however my next task is to instantiate the `mediaPlayer` class, and pass the URL of the video to be watched as a parameter.

I have attempted to code a `MediaPlayerTest`, whereby I instantiate the `mediaPlayer`, pass it a URL as a parameter, and then call the `start()` method, 
however I am getting the following errors when running my tester class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:271)
    at Media.mediaPlayer.start(mediaPlayer.java:34)
    at Media.MediaPlayerTest.main(MediaPlayerTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal graphics not initialized yet
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.getScreens(Screen.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.PrismGraphicsManager.<init>(PrismGraphicsManager.java:43)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<clinit>(WebEngine.java:290)
    ... 3 more
```

You can find the tester class and `mediaPlayer` class code below:

```
public class mediaPlayer extends Application {   

    // The url of the video to be played
    String url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CySfQY_lgr4";

    public mediaPlayer(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        webview.getEngine().load(url);

        webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And `MediaPlayerTest` class:

```
public class MediaPlayerTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer mp = new mediaPlayer("https://www.youtube.com/embed/CySfQY_lgr4");
            mp.start(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MediaPlayerTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Any help for solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not invoke `start()` yourself: it is invoked as part of a complex process when you call `launch()`.

So you can do:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List ;

public class MediaPlayer extends Application {   



  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }


  // The url of the video to be played
  private String url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CySfQY_lgr4";


  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    List<String> params = getParameters.getRaw();
    if (params.size() > 0) {
        url = params.get(0);
    }

    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(url);
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.show();
  }    
}
```

and then (if you want, but typically this is not a good approach):

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 *
 * @author Joe
 */
public class MediaPlayerTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            Application.launch(MediaPlayer.class, "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CySfQY_lgr4");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MediaPlayerTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously here the `MediaPlayerTest` class is somewhat redundant anyway: you can just run the `MediaPlayer` class directly.

The bottom line is that `Application` subclasses represent the entry point of the application, and as such they are not designed to be reusable. If you want to reuse your `MediaPlayer` class elsewhere, then refactor it so it's not an `Application` subclass. See [Java: How do I start a standalone application from the current one when both are in the same package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are)

Comment: Hi James, thanks a lot for your response, it certainly helped clear a few things up. The reason I wanted to use the tester method, was because I was planning on having a number of buttons on a section of my GUI, clicking each one would launch a seperate video. Is there any way I can accomplish this? The controllers for all of the buttons lie in the same controller class.

Comment: Make the class encapsulating the web view just a regular class, I.e. Not a subclass of `Application `. Then just reference it in the button handlers. This is very similar to the question I linked in the answer.