# Mute a WebView in JavaFX, is it possible?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-webview

Very simple. Is it possible to mute or control the volume of a JavaFX WebView? I googled for a while but I can't find any mention of this. I looked at the code for `WebView` and `WebEngine` and there doesn't seem to be anything about controlling the volume.

I still need other `MediaPlayer`s in the same app to work and produce sound, so, I can't mute the whole application.

Comment: Are we assuming that sound only comes from `<video>` and `<audio>` elements in the WebView’s content?

Comment: @VGR: I wasn't, but that'd be much better than nothing.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the web pages you're displaying, and to some extent how you're loading them, it should be pretty straightforward to do this by executing some Javascript via `WebEngine.executeScript(...)`.

Comment: It's any web page, as it's up to the user. They can type any URL they want.

Comment: So once the web page is loaded, you can do, e.g. `webEngine.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('video').forEach(function(vid) { vid.muted=true;});");` (my Javascript skills are a bit rusty, that might not be 100% correct, but you should get the idea. If the web page might insert audio/video after the page is loaded, then it may get a bit trickier.

Comment: @James_D: I'll probably do that as a workaround if I don't find a good solution, that is, something robust from the Java side of things.

Comment: You can try this solution-[Instantianting a webview with media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274699/instantiating-a-web-view-media-player-within-a-javafx-application)

Comment: @ViníciosRodrigues: that answer shows a plain WebView opening a YouTube URL. I don't see anything that would allow me to control the sound/volume there. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is [an unresolved issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091712) in JDK issue tracker regarding this problem which has been there for about 6 years now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We all know that it is a missing part of API, so what can you do to implement it on your own? Let's think about what WebView really is:

> *The embedded browser component is based on WebKit [...]*
>   *By default WebKit doesn't support web page rendering. In order to render and display HTML content Oracle had to write its own renderer using Java Graphics 2D API.*

It means that the engine has to have implementation. Implementation of WebKit is located in `com.sun.webkit` package *(a considerable part of classes is just a wrapper for native calls)*. Of course, in most cases you don't want to use `com.sun.*` classes, but currently you're working with JavaFX, so it doesn't really matter.

If we jump a little in sun's sources, we can find `WCMediaPlayer.class` with some abstract audio methods like:

```
protected abstract void setRate(float rate);
protected abstract void setVolume(float volume);
protected abstract void setMute(boolean mute);
protected abstract void setSize(int w, int h);
protected abstract void setPreservesPitch(boolean preserve);
```

C'mon Java, let me call you:

```
volumeMethod = WCMediaPlayer.class.getDeclaredMethod("setVolume", float.class);
volumeMethod.setAccessible(true);
```

I appreciate your help but how can I get `WCMediaPlayer` instances? We have to look at references to `new WCMediaPlayerImpl()`. Gotcha! `WCGraphicsManager.class` creates MediaPlayer by `fwkCreateMediaPlayer()` method, after all, it puts pointer and instance in `refMap`:

```
Field refMapField = WCGraphicsManager.class.getDeclaredField("refMap");
refMapField.setAccessible(true);
```

Fortunately, the manager has exposed `getGraphicsManager()` method to get an instance:

```
WCGraphicsManager graphicsManager = WCGraphicsManager.getGraphicsManager();
refMap = (Map<Integer, Ref>) refMapField.get(graphicsManager);
```

Catched map contains `Ref` instances (there are also other `WC*` instances) so you have to filter them:

```
Collection<WCMediaPlayer> mediaPlayers = refMap.values().stream()
    .filter(ref -> ref instanceof WCMediaPlayer)
    .map(ref -> (WCMediaPlayer) ref)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You probably expect working example so here is code that I used:

[image: WebEngineTest Preview]

```
public class WebEngineTest extends Application {

    private Map<Integer, Ref> refMap;
    private Method volumeMethod;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRAZBSoAsgs");

        Field refMapField = WCGraphicsManager.class.getDeclaredField("refMap");
        refMapField.setAccessible(true);

        volumeMethod = WCMediaPlayer.class.getDeclaredMethod("setVolume", float.class);
        volumeMethod.setAccessible(true);

        WCGraphicsManager graphicsManager = WCGraphicsManager.getGraphicsManager();
        refMap = (Map<Integer, Ref>) refMapField.get(graphicsManager);

        Button button = new Button("Volume");
        button.setOnAction(event -> setVolume(0.1f));

        Group group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll(webView, button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 625, 625);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        Collection<WCMediaPlayer> mediaPlayers = this.getMediaPlayers();
        mediaPlayers.forEach(mediaPlayer -> setVolumeMethod(mediaPlayer, volume));
    }

    private void setVolumeMethod(Object instance, Object... args) {
        try {
            volumeMethod.invoke(instance, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Collection<WCMediaPlayer> getMediaPlayers() {
        return refMap.values().stream()
                .filter(ref -> ref instanceof WCMediaPlayer)
                .map(ref -> (WCMediaPlayer) ref)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Finally, remember about the order of these calls. For instance, `refMap` doesn't contain all `Refs` until the state of engine is not `SUCCEEDED` or `WCGraphicsManager.getGraphicsManager()` returns `null` if graphic element is not created at all.

Probably, the best way is to combine these solutions. It's hard to support web technology mix without scenerio and poor API provided by JavaFX. You can also try to embed another browser, like Chromium.

Comment: Tricky and smart ^^ . But your code didn't work for me, i'm using Java 9 and most of the com.sun.* [APIs are unsupported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096) . com.sun.webkit is unavailable.

Comment: They're trying to remove and block much more, for example reflections or unsafe :/ Anyway, he didn't specified his environment and even if he want to run this on Java 9, he can use --add-exports flag

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and I understand this sort of hacks ties you to a single version. What I didn't understand is your comment about engine not being in `SUCCEEDED` state.

Comment: I meant that the manager adds Refs while it is in loading state, so you should wait until it ends loading. States like 'SUCCEEDED' or 'RUNNING' describe current status of page loading, it comes from LoadWorker listener

Answer (score 10):

Right now, there is **NO** such API for sound system in *WebView* or *WebEngine* Control.

But you could inject **JavaScript** to mute/unmute and control sounds. This method, only works with HTML5 elements **< video >** or **< audio >**, because items like **Flash** or **JS** initialized audio is impossible to restrict in general. I have created example program for you:

[image: WebView mute/unmute - program]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        WebView myWebView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = myWebView.getEngine();
        //dirty code xD

        Button btn = new Button("Load Youtube");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> engine.load("http://www.youtube.com/embed/A6hrw6KGdtM?autoplay=1"));

        Button btn2 = new Button("Mute");
        btn2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> engine.executeScript(getJSAudioVideo(true)));

        Button btn3 = new Button("Unmute");
        btn3.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> engine.executeScript(getJSAudioVideo(false)));

        Button btn4 = new Button("+");
        btn4.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> engine.executeScript(getJSSoundVolume(0.9)));

        Button btn5 = new Button("-");
        btn5.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> engine.executeScript(getJSSoundVolume(0.1)));

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(myWebView, btn, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Mute a WebView in JavaFX, is it possible?");

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param mute
     * @return JS code for mute/unmute
     */
    public String getJSAudioVideo(boolean mute){
        return "var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'),\n" +
                "    audios = document.querySelectorAll('listen');\n" +
                "    [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.muted = "+String.valueOf(mute)+"; });\n" +
                "    [].forEach.call(audios, function(audio) { audio.muted = "+String.valueOf(mute)+"; });";
    }

    /**
     * @param volume
     * @return JS code for setting volume sound
     */
    public String getJSSoundVolume(double volume){
        //max 1.0, min 0.0 Default: 1.0
        double _volume = (volume > 1.0 || volume < 0.0) ? 1.0 : volume;

        return "var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'),\n" +
                "    audios = document.querySelectorAll('listen');\n" +
                "    [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.volume = "+String.valueOf(_volume)+"; });\n" +
                "    [].forEach.call(audios, function(audio) { audio.volume = "+String.valueOf(_volume)+"; });";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To say about **WebView** , it is an extension of the Node class. It encapsulates a WebEngine object, incorporates HTML content into an application's scene, and provides properties and methods to apply effects and transformations. The getEngine() method called on a WebView object returns a web engine associated with it. [Source](http://The%20WebView%20class%20is%20an%20extension%20of%20the%20Node%20class.%20It%20encapsulates%20a%20WebEngine%20object,%20incorporates%20HTML%20content%20into%20an%20application's%20scene,%20and%20provides%20properties%20and%20methods%20to%20apply%20effects%20and%20transformations.%20The%20getEngine()%20method%20called%20on%20a%20WebView%20object%20returns%20a%20web%20engine%20associated%20with%20it.)

So WebView doesn't support any APIs for mute/volume control right now. There is an API to mute the content loaded in the MediaPlayer (ie.,)

To get the status of muteProperty: [Source link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#muteProperty--)

```
public BooleanProperty muteProperty()
```

To check the mute condition : [Source link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#isMute--)

```
public final boolean isMute()
```

To mute the video set the value to true: [Source link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setMute-boolean-)

```
public final void setMute(boolean value)
```

OR otherwise use the JavaScript API to mute the Video/Audio:

```
getElementById("Your video Id");
```

and set the control to Mute by :

```
vid.muted = true;
```

[Source Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_muted.asp)