# How to call the Java file from another Java file

Tags: java, javafx, launch, stage

I've been having difficulties calling a Java file that I've created from another Java file that would contain the UI elements. Here is the Java code that I'm trying to call:

```
public class XzibitVideo extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String path = "Data/Video/Clip.flv";
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(mediaView);
        //borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Black");
        //borderPane.setBottom(addToolBar());

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1024, 800);
        scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.BLACK);

        stage.setTitle("Media Player");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.setOnError(()->System.out.println("media error"+ mediaPlayer.getError().toString()));
    }
}
```

I've tried a couple of methods to call it, but im afraid none of them worked. for example,

```
XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
programVideo.start();

XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
programVideo.run();

XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
programVideo.main();
```

*I've also tried adding arguements/parameters, but with no luck:

```
XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
programVideo.start(Stage stage);
```

If anyone has any idea on how to properly call this function i would be extremely grateful! I've been working on this part for way too long, I'm losing all hope.. :(

Comment: `programVideo.start()` - but your `start(Stage stage)` method takes 1 param - Stage, so you probably call start()  method from super class and maybe that method in super class does nothing

Comment: programVideo.start(Stage stage); - this is an error. you should pass an argument here : e.g.  `Stage s = new Stage(); programVideo.start(s); `

Comment: `XzibitVideo.main(new String[0]);` or `Application.launch(XzibitVideo.class);`

Comment: i tried all of your suggesstions, and they all present me with this error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only" (I believe this is the only part of the error message that might be of some help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
    programVideo.launch(XzibitVideo.class);
    this.dispose();
```

Comment: It's bad practice to call a static method from a non-static context.

Comment: Thanks a million!! you are the best!! This definitely got my code to work, and thanks to everyone else who helped explain this issue to me!! I've been stuck on this part for weeks, almost gave up!

Have a great day everyone!!

Comment: I honestly think if you need to do this, you have your program structured incorrectly.

Comment: after playing around a bit, this code gets it done too (and i think it's faster and safer aswell)


`XzibitVideo.launch(XzibitVideo.class);`

Answer (score 0):

CLASSPATH defines where to look for classes. You can set CLASSPATH as environmental variable (in a way depending on your OS), or you can provide it a command-line parameter when invoking Java.
The class files can be in another directory, or in a JAR - anyway you have to point to it with CLASSPATH.

Comment: I'm not quiet sure I understand the relevance here... The problem isnt the ClassPath because it is in the same package as other java files that I have managed to call successfully, However i called them through the .run() function available in them. ..
Unfortunetly, this java file, as u can see, doesnt have a run function, instead it has a "start" function, and i'm not sure how to call that :)

Comment: So perhaps your question should be rather: "how to call methods from class `XzibitVideo` , which extends `Application`". Any javadoc for it? As `class XzibitVideo` has a main(), it suggests it can be run as an external program.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the application from another class with

```
Application.launch(XzibitVideo.class);
```

Note:

1. this method will block until the JavaFX platform exits
2. You can only call `launch()` once per application (i.e. once per JVM lifecycle)

It's not really clear why you want to do this. The `start()` method in the `Application` subclass is (as its name implies) the starting point for the application. `main` methods are only even included in JavaFX applications for the benefit of runtime environments that can't launch JavaFX Application classes natively. Consequently, `Application` subclasses are inherently not reusable. If you want `XzibitVideo` to be resuable, you should refactor it so it is not a subclass of `Application`, and just create a simple `Application` subclass whose `start()` method refers to it.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are

Comment: Thanks alot James, I might need to do more research. I dont like not knowing things, especially when a significant part of my program is using it.

also, i've tried `Application.launch(XzibitVideo.class);` and it worked aswell :)

thank you so much for your help, I'll keep researching and experimenting and hopefully i'll have a better understanding regarding this.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Stage stage = new Stage(); // or using another constructor of class Stage
XzibitVideo programVideo = new XzibitVideo();
programVideo.start(stage);
```

Comment: I've added the constructor just like you introduced here.. but i'm getting an error now when calling it... 

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only"

I believe this is the only part of the error message that might be of some help