# is it possible to extend the javafx class you created

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class jfxApp extends Application{

}
```

Can I extend the jfxApp I created like this?

```
public class newApp extends jfxApp{

}
```

Comment: Yes you can, but your class names should being with uppercase letters.

Comment: or is it possible to create javafx panes like gridpane without extending Application class? Which metttans you can now create an instance of it in the main class in which you extend the application class

Comment: Yes, you can extend another Java Object - did you try it?

Comment: You can, but I'm not sure what the point would be. The major use of an `Application ` subclass is as the startup of your JavaFX application; that is specifically implemented by the `start()` method. If you override your existing `start()` method you may as well just create a new `Application` subclass. If you don't override it, it's essentially going to be the same application, unless you are doing something moderately sophisticated. Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have written over one thousand lines of code in a single javafx class and more codes are needed and I think it would be better to have each page or categories to have is own class

Comment: another option which I think is to create different classes for different categories and later instanciate them inside the main class

Comment: Well yes, obviously you should split them into different classes. But those other classes shouldn't be subclasses of `Application`

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are (or many other examples) for examples of how to break your application into separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to extend something that is already extending something.  It will give you access to all methods in jfxApp, Application and newApp.