# Call the start(Stage) method in javafx class to another javafx class (no fxml)

Tags: java, javafx, methods, call

I have a ParkingLot class and a Parkingmethod class, I write a few methods in Parkingmethod class. Now I want to call the Parkingmethod class in ParkingLot class, what should I do? 
Also, if I envoke one method (which calls some other methods in this class) to ParkingLot class, will other methods in Parkingmethod class be called?

```
public static void main(String[] args){//here is the main method in ParkingLot class

    Parkingmethod object = new Parkingmethod();
    object.start(*//Should I build a new stage here？？？*);
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Both classes extend Application and use javafx!!!

Comment: The `Application` class represents the entire application. So you should only have one `Application` class in your application. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are

Comment: @James_D Thank you. I put all my methds in one lass and it works.

Comment: I wouldn't advise that