# Opening java file with button (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx

I've got an app made in javafx and another class with menu in this project. In this menu I've got two buttons and one works (exit buuton) and I want buttonStart to open my Main class. How to launch it?

```
Button buttonStart = new Button("START GAME");

Button buttonExit = new Button("EXIT");

    buttonExit.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.exit(0));
```

My menu:

```
package pl.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Menu extends Application {

    private BorderPane layout;
    private Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        layout = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(layout, 720, 480);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #F9A825;");

        Button buttonStart = new Button("START GAME");
        buttonStart.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        buttonStart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #E65100;");

        Button buttonExit = new Button("EXIT");
        buttonExit.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        buttonExit.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #E65100;");

        buttonExit.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.exit(0));
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonStart, buttonExit);

        layout.setCenter(hbox);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

Class which I wanna launch:

```
package pl.main;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main extends Application {

    private HashMap<KeyCode, Boolean> keys = new HashMap<KeyCode, Boolean>();
    private ArrayList<Node> blocks = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private Pane appRoot = new Pane();

    private Pane gameRoot = new Pane();
    private Pane uiRoot = new Pane();

    private Node player;
    private Point2D playerGoDown = new Point2D(0, 0);
    private Point2D playerGoRight = new Point2D(0, 0);
    private boolean canJump = true;
    private int levelWidth;

    private void initContent() {
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(720, 480);
        // BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE);

        levelWidth = LevelData.LEVEL1[0].length();

        for (int i = 0; i < LevelData.LEVEL1.length; i++) {
            String map = LevelData.LEVEL1[i] + LevelData.LEVEL2[i]+ LevelData.LEVEL1[i]+ LevelData.LEVEL2[i]+ LevelData.LEVEL1[i]+ LevelData.LEVEL2[i];

            String line = map;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
                switch (line.charAt(j)) {
                case '0':
                    break;
                case '1':
                    Node block = createEntity(j * 30, i * 30, 30, 30, Color.ORANGE);
                    blocks.add(block);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        player = createEntity(0, 350, 40, 40, Color.YELLOW);
        // a ????????????
        player.translateXProperty().addListener((a, old, newValue) -> {
            int offset = newValue.intValue();
            //if (offset > 360 && offset < levelWidth - 360) {
                gameRoot.setLayoutX(-(offset - 360));
            //}
        });
        appRoot.getChildren().addAll(background, gameRoot, uiRoot);
    }

    private void update() {
        if (isPressed(KeyCode.W) && player.getTranslateY() >= 0) {
            jumpPlayer();
        }
        if (playerGoDown.getY() < 10) {
            playerGoDown = playerGoDown.add(0, 1);
        }
        movePlayerY((int) playerGoDown.getY());

        if (player.getTranslateX() <= levelWidth - 5) {
            // movePlayerX(5);
            movePlayerRight();
        }

        if (playerGoRight.getX() < 0) {
            playerGoRight = playerGoRight.add(0, 1);
        }
        movePlayerX((int) playerGoRight.getX());
    }

    private void movePlayerX(int value) {
        boolean movingRight = value > 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(value); i++) {
            for (Node block : blocks) {
                if (player.getBoundsInParent().intersects(block.getBoundsInParent())) {
                    if (movingRight) {
                        if (player.getTranslateX() + 40 == block.getTranslateX()) {
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (player.getTranslateX() == block.getTranslateX() + 60) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() + (movingRight ? 1 : -1));
        }
    }

    private void movePlayerY(int value) {
        boolean movingDown = value > 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(value); i++) {
            for (Node block : blocks) {
                if (player.getBoundsInParent().intersects(block.getBoundsInParent())) {
                    if (movingDown) {
                        if (player.getTranslateY() + 40 == block.getTranslateY()) {
                            canJump = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (player.getTranslateY() == block.getTranslateY() + 60) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() + (movingDown ? 1 : -1));
        }
    }

    private void jumpPlayer() {
        if (canJump) {
            playerGoDown = playerGoDown.add(0, -10);
            canJump = false;
        }
    }

    private void movePlayerRight() {
        playerGoRight = playerGoRight.add(10, 0);
    }

    private Node createEntity(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
        Rectangle entity = new Rectangle(w, h);
        entity.setTranslateX(x);
        entity.setTranslateY(y);
        entity.setFill(color);
        gameRoot.getChildren().add(entity);
        return entity;

    }

    private boolean isPressed(KeyCode key) {
        return keys.getOrDefault(key, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        initContent();
        Scene scene = new Scene(appRoot);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> keys.put(event.getCode(), true));
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> keys.put(event.getCode(), false));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Jetpack gameplay");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                update();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

In future I wanna change current Main.java into ordinary class because now I have two classes which works independently.

Comment: please add your full code.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean by "Launch open my main class"? Typically the main class just starts the application, but obviously (since the buttons must already be displayed) your application is already running at this point.

Comment: You should not have two different `Application` subclasses, if these are supposed to be part of the same application. The `Application` class represents the entire application and its lifecycle. If you want the UI to be reusable, you need to define it in a class that can be reused (the `Application` subclass really can't be easily reused). See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464698/java-how-do-i-start-a-standalone-application-from-the-current-one-when-both-are

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on another page, you have to load the game scene.

Look at `Scene` class in JavaDoc.

Once you have your scene, you just have to add an ActionEvent to your button that will display your page.